# Parsing a string with, seemingly, no delimiter

Tags: c#, .net, string

I have the following string that I need to parse out so I can insert them into a DB. The delimiter is "`":

```
`020             Some Description       `060       A Different Description        `100       And Yet Another       `
```

I split the string into an array using this

```
var responseArray = response.Split('`');
```

So then each item in the `responseArrray[]` looks like this: `020      Some Description`

How would I get the two different parts out of that array?  The 1st part will be either 3 or 4 characters long.  2nd part will be no more then 35 characters long.

Due to some ridiculous strangeness beyond my control there is random amounts of space between the 1st and 2nd part.

Comment: `Split` on space then `Trim`?

Comment: Hmm, how will that work when the 2nd part of each, the description, will have spaces in it as well?

Comment: Find index of *first* space, select substring to get letters, substring second half, then `trim()`

Comment: `Split`, `Trim`, then `Join` all but first? Or find the first space and `Substring` then `Trim`.

Comment: Another low-tech answer since you know the first part will be 3-4 characters and there's guaranteed to be at least once space, the 5th character will always begin the second data field, whereupon you can trim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or put the other two answers together, and get something that's more complete:

```
string[] response = input.Split(`);

foreach (String str in response) {
  int splitIndex = str.IndexOf(' ');

  string num = str.Substring(0, splitIndex);  
  string desc = str.Substring(splitIndex);      
  desc.Trim();
}
```

so, basically you use the first space as a delimiter to create 2 strings. Then you trim the second one, since trim only applies to leading and trailing spaces, not everything in between.

Edit: this a straight implementation of Brad M's comment.

Comment: :) Yup, I was in process of implementing his solution when I happened to check back in here.  Thanks, to both of you, works like a charm.

Comment: how is that remove the spaces? first part can contain spaces too.and  you are not filtering the character lenght

Comment: The first part doesn't contain spaces because the ``` character is being used as a delimiter.  The only place with spaces that aren't wanted is in between the number and the description.  Character length should not matter either, as there is a delimiter.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this solution:

```
var inputString = "`020             Some Description       `060       A Different Description        `100       And Yet Another       `";

int firstWordLength = 3;
int secondWordMaxLength = 35;

var result =inputString.Split('`')
            .SelectMany(x => new[]
             {
               new String(x.Take(firstWordLength).ToArray()).Trim(), 
               new String(x.Skip(firstWordLength).Take(secondWordMaxLength).ToArray()).Trim()
             });
```

Here is the result in `LINQPad`:

[image]

Update: My first solution has some problems because the use of `Trim` after `Take`.Here is another approach with an extension method:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<string> GetWords(this string source,int firstWordLengt,int secondWordLenght)
    {
        List<string> words = new List<string>();
        foreach (var word in source.Split(new[] {'`'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
        {
            var parts = word.Split(new[] {' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            words.Add(new string(parts[0].Take(firstWordLengt).ToArray()));
            words.Add(new string(string.Join(" ",parts.Skip(1)).Take(secondWordLenght).ToArray()));
        }
        return words;
    }
}
```

And here is the test result:

[image]

Comment: Close, the firstword can be 3 or 4.  Thanks for the different approach though.

Comment: @RefractedPaladin there is one problem with that solution.I use Take before Trim.That might be cause some unexpected results.You might want first filter the spaces then take characters.You can easily do it with where,  `new String(x.Where(c => !char.IsWhiteSpace(c)).Take(firstWordLength).ToArray())`, but ofcourse this will remove all spaces and that would be a different problem :)

Comment: @RefractedPaladin I have added another solution I hope this helps.It's more correct and flexible than first one I guess.

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] entries = input.Split('`');

foreach (string s in entries)
   GetStringParts(s);

IEnumerable<String> GetStringParts(String input)
{
   foreach (string s in input.Split(' ')
      yield return s.Trim();
}
```

Trim only removes leading/trailing whitespace per [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trim%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), so spaces in the description won't hurt you.

Comment: I assumed that all leading/trailing spaces are not desired.

Comment: They aren't but I'm not sure this will work since won't it see the space between the 1st and 2nd part of the String as the same as the space inside the 2nd part?

Comment: I don't think this will work, as the spaces will still be between the characters (020    Some Description)

Comment: You are absolutely correct. I edited my answer to be "more" correct, but to make it perfect the last split needs to do the substring from other answers, which seemed a bit redundant.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the first part by finding the first space and make a `substring`. The second is also a `Substring`. Try something like this.

```
    foreach(string st in response)
    {
        int index = response.IndexOf(' ');
        string firstPart = response.Substring(0, index);


        //string secondPart = response.Substring(response.Lenght-35);
        //better use this
        string secondPart = response.Substring(index);
        secondPart.Trim();
    }
```

Comment: Where did you come up with the "response.Length-35" part?  Shouldn't it be (Index, response.length)?

Comment: Oh i read it wrong. I thought the second part would be exact 35 chars. So you're right but after `string secondPart = response.Substring(index)`you should make a `secondPart.Trim();`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

string response = "`020             Some Description`060       A Different Description        `100       And Yet Another`";
            var responseArray = response.Split('`');

```
        string[] splitArray = {};
        string result = "";

        foreach (string it in responseArray)
        {
            splitArray = it.Split(' ');
            foreach (string ot in splitArray)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ot))
                    result += "-" + ot.Trim();
            }
        }

        splitArray = result.Substring(1).Split('-');
```

Answer (score 0):

If the first part is an integer 
And you need to account for some empty
For me the first pass was empty

```
public void parse()
{
    string s = @"`020             Some Description       `060       A Different Description        `100       And Yet Another       `";
    Int32 first;
    String second;
    if (s.Contains('`'))
    {
        foreach (string firstSecond in s.Split('`'))
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(firstSecond);
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(firstSecond))
            {
                firstSecond.TrimStart();
                Int32 firstSpace = firstSecond.IndexOf(' ');
                if (firstSpace > 0)
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("'" + firstSecond.Substring(0, firstSpace) + "'");
                    if (Int32.TryParse(firstSecond.Substring(0, firstSpace), out first))
                    {
                        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("'" + firstSecond.Substring(firstSpace-1) + "'");
                        second = firstSecond.Substring(firstSpace).Trim();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```